# Invalid cast with generic type

Tags: c#, templates, interface, casting, xamarin.forms

I want to make a function that takes a Position object and returns the latitude and longitude of this Position as a formated string.

But the problem is that I have 2 Position objects : one from Xamarin Forms and another one from a geolocation nugget.

Position from Xamarin forms:

```
public Position(double latitude, double longitude);
public double Latitude { get; }
public double Longitude { get; }
...
```

And Position from the geolocation nugget:

```
public Position();
public Position(Position position);
public double Latitude { get; set; }
public double Longitude { get; set; }
...
```

In order to have the two types working as one I made an interface :

```
interface IPosition
{
    double Latitude
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    double Longitude
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

So my function should accept those two objects in parameter as follow :

```
public static string PositionToCoordonates<T>(T p)
    {
        return ((IPosition)p).Latitude.ToString().Replace(",", ".") + " ," + ((IPosition)p).Longitude.ToString().Replace(",", ".");
    }
```

Unfortunatly it throws the error "**System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.**" at runtime.

What am I doing wrong ? I guess that I need some kind of dynamic cast but I'm not sure.

Comment: How are you calling `PositionToCoordinates()`.  Consider adding a constraint on T such as `PositionToCoordonates<T>(T p) where T : IPosition`.

Comment: I understand the reasoning behind creating the `IPosition` How is it implemented. I get the feeling you may be confusing how to use it. The constraint may we the solution but you need to clarify how you intend to use the method

Comment: @LordWilmore Thx for your answer. I call it like this : GpsDistanceHelper.PositionToCoordonates(currentPosition); So I should try like this ? : GpsDistanceHelper.PositionToCoordonates<T>(currentPosition) where T : IPosition; ?

Comment: @Doctor There's no reason for the method to be generic in the first place.  You aren't getting anything out of it being generic and then constrained.  Just *don't make it generic in the first place*.

Comment: @LordWilmore that makes no sense, if it can only be one type than have the parameter be of that type.  there is zero need for generics here

Comment: @Nkosi yeah there maybe some confusion indeed ;-). What I want is to use the method with the two Position object without having to write anything specific.

Comment: @maccettura Good point.  Doctor, please ignore me, I'm talking rubbish

Comment: @Doctor create a value object that can be implicitly converted from the two position types and have that as the parameter type of the method.

Comment: @Doctor I think some tutorials on interfaces would greatly benefit you, you seem to have a disconnect on how they work.

Comment: I don't get the point why you not simply check something like `if (p is Position) ... `. Do you want to strictly avoid this kind of stuff?

Comment: @sprinter252 hum I did not think of it. Its also a good idear ! Even though I find it a little less OOP than what Gabriel Negut suggested :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both your `Position` classes implement `IPosition`, all you need is

```
public static string PositionToCoordonates(IPosition position)
```

There is no need for generics.

On the other hand, if those classes do not implement that interface (and that would be the case if you created it), you will have a bit of code duplication.

```
public static string PositionToCoordonates(Geolocation.Position position)
{
    return PositionToCoordinates(position.Latitude, position.Longitude);
}

public static string PositionToCoordonates(Xamarin.Position position)
{
    return PositionToCoordinates(position.Latitude, position.Longitude);
}

private static string PositionToCoordonates(double latitude, double longitude)
{
    return string.Format(...);
}
```

As a clarification on the second part of my answer: In C#, classes have to declare they implement an interface, it is not enough to have the properties/methods defined on that interface.

So, in your example, `position as IPosition` will be `null`, and `(IPosition) position` will throw an exception.

For the above casts to work, `Position` has to be declared as

```
class Position : IPosition
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. The two position objects are not mine. So I can't have them implement my IPosition interface. Now what I would like to avoid is the code duplication that you propose. But maybe there is no other way ;-)

Comment: As an alternative, you could look into `dynamic`, but that would be overkill for this particular case.

Comment: @Doctor there is no code duplication.  All the "special sauce" is in the `PositionToCoordonates(double latitude, double longitude)` method.  The other two are simply overloads that extract the actual values needed and call the "special sauce"

Comment: @maccettura Ok then I'll try that asap. Thx you all !

Comment: I've noticed that one `Position` is a `struct` and the another one is a `class`... One more reason to support the @GabrielNegut's approach.

Answer (score 3):

`PositionToCoordonates` shouldn't be generic.  Making it generic is a way of saying that the parameter can be *of any type*.  Your parameter *can't* be of any type, it needs to be an `IPosition`.  Make the parameter of type `IPosition`, so that callers aren't allowed to pass in objects of another type (as they won't work), and you'll be able to see, from any compiler errors, what callers are passing in an object of the wrong type.

Note that once you change the parameter there will no longer be a reason for the method to be generic, nor will you need to be casting the parameter in the method body.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I thought of this. But I would still have to cast the Position object to IPosition. Don't you think I would have the same error ?

Comment: @Doctor Why would you need to cast a variable to the type of that variable?  What do you think that's going to accomplish?  How are you expecting to get a cannot cast exception using properties of an `IPosition` on a variable of type `IPosition`?

Comment: @Servy I think the problem is that the two types the OP wants to access dont actually implement IPosition.  OP is misunderstood and thinks just creating an Interface with the same fields will automatically allow it to work

Comment: @maccettura You are right. The two Position objects don't implement the interface. But they are not my objects so I can't change that. That is why I was hopping for some kind of smart cast.

Comment: @Doctor Use Gabriels answer then.  Its exactly what you need

Comment: @Doctor Then *you* will need to convert the objects into objects that implement the interface.  Casting is merely a way of telling the compiler that an object is actually of a type that it doesn't realize it is, not a way of turning an object into something it isn't.

Comment: @Servy So How can I "cast" the two Position objects to another one of my creation that would implements the IPosition ?

Comment: @Doctor dont do that haha

Comment: @Doctor Create a constructor that creates an instance given one of those two objects.

Answer (score 1):

Because both `Positions` are not implemented by you you can't just invent an interface to use it for casts imho. In this scenario I would probably handle this as follows:

```
void Main()
{
    var position1 = new Position1() { Lat = 10, Lon = 5 };
    var position2 = new Position1() { Lat = 12, Lon = 3 };
    Console.WriteLine(GetLatLon(position1));
    Console.WriteLine(GetLatLon(position2));
}

static string GetLatLon<T>(T input) 
{
    var position1 = input as Position1;
    var position2 = input as Position2;
    if (position1 != null)
    {
        return $"{position1.Lat}-{position1.Lon}";
    }
    if (position2 != null)
    {
        return $"{position2.Lat}-{position2.Lon}";
    }
    throw new ArgumentException(nameof(input));
}

class Position1 
{
    public double Foo { get; set ;}
    public int Lat { get; set;}
    public int Lon { get; set;}
}

class Position2 
{
    public int Lat { get; set; }
    public int Lon { get; set; }
}
```

Dynamic seems to be too heavy for this scenario where only 2 possible types are involved. I don't know if the generic parameter is needed exactly but I left it in the hope, that boxing/unboxing will be avoided one time.